# jQuery-UI Datepicker CSS problem

Tags: css, jquery-ui, themes

I've got this pretty simple HTML page with a jQuery datepicker:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>jQuery Datepicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../App_Themes/Default/ui.datepicker.css" type="text/css"
        media="screen" title="Smoothness" />

    <script src="../Shared/Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../Shared/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.5.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(PageLoad);

        function PageLoad() {
            $('#textBox').datepicker();
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="textBox" />
</body>
</html>
```

The datepicker itself seems to work perfectly but I can't apply my theme. Am I missing something really stupid here?

Thanks !!!!

Comment: It works fine for me. Check your path and CSS validity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My problem wasn't about the CSS validity or relative paths .... I was just referencing the wrong version of CSS files for my jQuery-ui version. To all of you that had a similar problem make sure you download the correct theme's version for your jQuery-ui scripts.

Thanks.

Comment: Its a great/terrible feeling when you realize that you knew what you were doing all along but failed somewhere in the execution :)

Answer (score 8):

If you load jQueryUI through Google, make sure the jQueryUI CSS theme has the same version as the jQueryUI library.

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Check the above code, both use 1.8.5. But if you load 1.8 instead of 1.8.5 for the theme the datapicker won't show up.

Answer (score 3):

I got the problem which is opposite of yours. Wherein i forgot to insert the below line in my head section and my datepicker is taking the css from my template. After including it in my head section, I can able to view the datetime picker with googleapi's css

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

let's try with this ...

```
        function eds_admin_styles() {
          wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-datepicker-style' , '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
        }
        add_action('admin_print_styles', 'eds_admin_styles');
        function eds_admin_scripts() {
          wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
        }
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'eds_admin_scripts');
```

here is js

```
    (function($) {
      $('#jquery-datepicker').datepicker();
    }(jQuery));
```